# Alterar input number e somar valores de campos do form

Tags: jquery

Tenho um form com vários inputs number, cada input tem um atributo chamado `product_val` que contem um valor.

Preciso que ao alterar o conteúdo de um input (change), uma determinada função capture todos os inputs do form, pegue o valor do atributo e multiplique por seu value, após obter esse resultado, somar todos numa variavel.

Classe dos inputs: order_input_qnt

Resultado da soma: order_total_price

No [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w7ze1m68/1/)

```
jQuery(function ($)
{
 $('.order_input_qnt').on('change',function()
 {
  $(".order_total_price").html("...");

  var sum = 0;
  $(".order_input_qnt").each(function()
  {
     if ($(".order_input_qnt").val().length > 0) {
         var valor = parseFloat($(".order_input_qnt").attr("product_val")) * parseFloat($(".order_input_qnt").val());
         sum += valor;
     }
  });
  $(".order_total_price").html(sum.toFixed(2));

  });
});
```

Comment: Não consegui interpretar a pergunta. Seria possível vc descrever passo a passo as operações? Ex.: 1 - Somar o valor de todos os campos, 2 - Multiplicar o resultado.... etc....

Comment: @MarceloVieira editei o post

Comment: Seria isso? https://jsfiddle.net/w7ze1m68/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema no seu código está dentro do `each`. Na função de callback do `each` está tentando pegar o resultado de cada item para fazer o cálculo, porém ao utilizar `$('.order_input_qnt').val()` está pegando sempre o valor do primeiro item. Uma vez que `.order_input_qnt` representa uma coleção de elementos e o `val()` retornará apenas o valor de um elemento (no caso do primeiro).

Você pode utilizar o `this` dentro da função de callback do `each`, que faz referência ao item atual na iteração, por exemplo:

```
jQuery(function ($)
{
  $('.order_input_qnt').on('change',function()
  {
      $(".order_total_price").html("...");

      var sum = 0;
      $(".order_input_qnt").each(function()
      {
        var val = $(this).val()
         if (val.length > 0) {
             var valor = parseFloat($(this).attr("product_val")) * parseFloat(val);
             sum += valor;
         }
      });
      $(".order_total_price").html(sum.toFixed(2));

  });
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w7ze1m68/2/